# OpenCV freeing memory?

Tags: c++, image, memory, opencv

If I getting video input, I need a image to capture a frame. Does the image need to be released after every loop?

i.e.

```
IplImage* frame = 0;
while (1)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame (camera);
    cvShowImage ("Window", frame);
    //would I need to add a cvReleaseImage (&frame) here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont need to relase image frame but when the while loop is terminated then you need to release camera ;`cvReleaseCapture(&camera);`

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense